# mysql left join if not exist or value equals 0

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

```
select a.*, b.status
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.bid = b.id
WHERE b.status = null or b.status=0 # thanks didnt mean to put == 

select a.*, b.status
 FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.bid = b.id
 WHERE b.status < 1
```

# hoping this would pull 0 and no matches but didnt work either

The above does not work. I am using mysql4.

I need a way to only pull records who are null meaning there is no match or status 0 in table b.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the problem with my actualy complex query was another part of the where check and the is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IS NULL` is a proper way to compare value with `null` (`null` = `null` evaluates as `null`(false)).

```
select a., b.status FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.bid = b.id WHERE b.status IS NULL or b.status = 0
```

Comment: Ack, optionally one can use `<=>` if it is not known beforehand whether either of the compared values is NULL or not. Not needed in this case, just elaborating :)

Answer (score 1):

```
b.status IS NULL
```

that should work in your `WHERE` clause